# Is there any way to force Windows 7 to refresh the taskbar previews?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, preview

I frequently find that some of the window previews in the Windows 7 taskbar will be lost, especially after a window has been minimized or hidden for a considerable period of time.  Instead of the normal preview of the window I just see a gray box with the program icon in it.

Example:

[image]

This is a pain when I have a dozen Firefox windows open and can no longer quickly distinguish windows in the preview.  Is there anything I can do to alleviate this?  Any way to tell windows to keep around the previews longer or some key combo that will refresh all of the previews?

Comment: I'll add this here since it isn't really an answer to the actual question. I would suggest training yourself to use ALT-TAB to switch apps. It is purely anecdotal, but I've never seen a preview blank out there.

Comment: Here here! Alt tab ftw.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

1. Click on the `Start` Orb > right-click `Computer` > click `Properties` > click `Advanced system settings`
2. Under `Performance` click `Settings` > Check if `Save taskbar thumbnail previews` option is selected or not.
3. If not selected, select it.

That should save the thumbnail previews and you will not get the grey application icon preview.